# Keyboard layout per window

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

As you know when you change keyboard layout with alt-shift it affects all the windows of current application. Is it there any program which changes the behavior to per window?

OS: Windows 7

Comment: For more information: do you need this for an application in particular? If for several, please give some examples.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

In the "Text Services and Input Languages" screen (where you define the keyboard layouts and set the default one), go to the "Advanced Key Settings" tab. There you can assign a different hotkey per input language (=keyboard layout).

Once you've assigned the hotkeys to the desired languages, an AutoHotkey script could trigger the hotkey when it detects a specific window opens or has the focus (=is activated). The window can be detected by title, class, text in the window, ... or even a mix of two or three.

Comment: I did such as script, and it works quite well. It wasn't easy though: https://gist.github.com/christianrondeau/00d7cd5848f33e029f00ce2b6b935ab9

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, the changes are global.

But you can setup a [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and run the application in seamless mode with a different keyboard layout. :)

Comment: Changes in layout are indeed linked to the application, not the individual windows from it. However, unless the application is able to work with several instances together, I don't think that the virtualization solution will be appropriate.

Comment: @Gnoupi - while it 'might' be an overkill, how is it inappropriate? it works.

Comment: It won't work if the several windows of the same application work on the same data, in the back. This is what I meant. It will work only in a context like Word, where each window can be for a different document.

Comment: @Gnoupi - quite so, but you can make use of folder sharing and access the same documents on a virtual machine ... so, depending on the scenario, virtualization is a viable option, never mind all the other benefits of using virtual computers. :)

Comment: Yes, but like I say, it requires the program to be able to have several instances on the same data. If so, then sure, virtualization will work.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is possible to do that without external applications.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/466207) suggest a configuration setting that I use and works for me.

Comment: Just a link to where to look for an answer would be more appropriate as a comment.  Answers should be self contained.  It would be better to include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution.