# Set Windows 8 to per-application input language mode

Tags: windows-8, input-languages

In Windows XP, Vista, 7 whenever one was using sevaral input languages, switching between applications would default input language for an application to defalut language.

For example when I have opened MS Word and switched input to type in Russian, switching to Command Prompt application would automatically set the input language to English (default). When I was going back to MS Word, language automatically was turning back to Russian as I left off.

So it was like a per-application input setting.

In Windows 8 an input language switch affects an enitre OS input. So if I want to type in a command in CMD, I have to manually switch to English.

How can I have Windows 8 to behave the way Windows 7 did with respect to input language switching?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

1. Open control panel
2. Switch to all items view
3. Click language
4. In the left hand side panel choose advanced settings
5. Check the box under switching inputs that says "Let me set a different input method for each app Windows"

Comment: Thank you very much! This extremely useful for login from locking screen (usually we don't see in language indicator while typing password, right?).

Comment: This works for Windows 10, too.

Comment: I came here from a ddg-search. This works in W10, but it's still annoying to set the keyboard each time the app launches. Does anyone know of a way to make Windows remember it?