# Find registry key for windows 8 per-application input method setting

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, input-languages

I had some trouble to adapt a windows 7 application for windows 8. The issue was windows 8 having a global input method on windows 8.

I found that the control panel setting "Let me set a different input method for each app Windows" solved my problem ([Set Windows 8 to per-application input language mode](https://superuser.com/questions/466180/set-windows-8-to-per-application-input-language-mode?rq=1)).

Now my question is : where can I find this setting in the windows 8 **registry** ?

I would like to retrieve this key in my application..

Answer (score 2):

This setting is stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask. The registry value itself is a binary value that represents a bitmask of various settings.
Its format is documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957204.aspx)

Unfortunately this document is a bit oudated and does not contain information about this particular setting. By experimenting with this value I have found that the settins is stored in bit 32. When this bit is on, input switches for each application separately.

```
Example of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask with setting on:
9e 1e 07 80 92 00 00 00
With setting off:
9e 1e 07 80 12 00 00 00
```

Here is a Powershell script example to turn it on:

```
$prefMask = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 'UserPreferencesMask').UserPreferencesMask
if (($prefMask[4] -band 0x80) -eq 0) {
  $prefMask[4] = ($prefMask[4] -bor 0x80)
  New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name 'UserPreferencesMask' -Value $prefMask -PropertyType ([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::Binary) -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Was tested on quite a bunch of win8.1 machines (both x86 and x64) and appears to work as expected.

Note that the setting takes effect immediately, but *displays wrong* in language panel settings dialog. So you need to logoff and logon back for panel settings to pick up the change.