# "Let me set a different input method for each app Windows" script activation

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-registry

i need to activate the option "Let me set a different input method for each app Windows" on several pcs, but it seems that i can do so only manually...

( "advanced keyboard settings" in windows setting)
[image: "Let me set a different input method for each app Windows" image]

i came across several solutions to this problem,

e.g.
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/839993/find-registry-key-for-windows-8-per-application-input-method-setting)
[here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6e76806-3b64-47e6-876e-ffbbc7438784/the-option-let-me-set-a-different-input-method-for-each-app-window?forum=w8itprogeneral)
[here](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/116793-let-me-set-different-input-method-each-app-window-registry-key.html)

but none of them seem to work properly, without the checkbox being manually marked.

is there a way to enable this option via script or some other registry key?
(preferably from a batch script / .reg file - *a test workstation has been restarted in between tries.)

Comment: Are you logging in and logging out of the user since you are modifying a HKCU registry key?

Comment: yes. i tried logging out  and also a full restart.