# How do I change the input language for a program being run as another user?

Tags: windows, keyboard, input-languages, runas

On Windows 8.1, alt-shift changes the input language/keyboard for all programs.  This works fine for applications that I'm running under my own user account.  But if I start a program with "runas", e.g.

`C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /profile /user:ff "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`,

alt-shift is ignored in the window, and alt-shift outside the window has no effect on the runas'ed program.

Is there any way to have input language changes apply to runas'ed programs as well?

This problem is not new to Windows 8.1; I saw the same thing in Windows 7.

Comment: Don't you change the language of the program within the program?

Comment: No, the input language is managed by Windows

Comment: Oh right didn't see *input* language sorry about that.

Comment: IMHO `alt-shift` is **not ignored**, input language switching applies with **no indication** in language panel. Verified even with `runas /user:myself notepad`, where `myself` is the username logged on currently. On Win-8 also check that [per-application input language](http://superuser.com/questions/466180/set-windows-8-to-per-application-input-language-mode/466207#466207) settings (not sure if it is _per-box_ or _per-user_). And has your `ff` user more languages installed anywise?

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior you describe (with runas /user:anotheruser), at least not with Google's Japanese IME on Windows 8.1.  I've tried toggling that per-window setting as well.  It's probably working for you because you're running it as the same user as the current session.  (Sorry if it was unclear that I was running it as another user.)

Comment: The `ff` user does have the input language and IME set up as well,  and I can even log in as `ff` and change the language, but it has no effect on the Firefox window running on my primary desktop.

Comment: Of course I have tried `runas /user:anotheruser` first, goes as described above. That experiment with `runas /user:myself` done to assure the _language indicator_ stays dead. But I'm switching CZ-EN-SK keyboards only; maybe that _Google_'s Japanese IME brings some new quality - so what about support.google.com? And to unblame Firefox, what behaviour if runasing another browser?

Comment: You are indeed correct!  Google Japanese Input is broken with this setup, while other languages work fine.