# Cannot switch Input Method globally back to English in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, input-languages

I'm using Windows 8.1, I have two input methods:

1. English(United States);
2. Chinese(Simplified, China).

The first one is the system default, the second one is a Pinyin Input Method by Google.

When I want to type in Chinese, I switch to Chinese using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. This switch seems to be global because all other windows I focus on later would use Chinese input.

However, when I switch the input method back to English, it only affects the current window. That is to say, when I go to another window or program, the Chinese input method is still on, and I have to switch it back to English again.

This is VERY annoying because I cannot keep track of input method status for every window. I wish to make the switch global such that I only need to switch once.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: More info required: Please check Control Panel settings of `Regional and Language` and `Keyboard`. Add info about these to your posting (note `edit` to the very left of you name)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open control panel
2. Switch to all items view
3. Click language
4. In the left hand side panel choose advanced settings
5. **Un-check** the box under switching inputs that says "Let me set a different input method for each app Windows"

This answer is just an adapted solution for that problem:
[Set Windows 8 to per-application input language mode](https://superuser.com/questions/466180/set-windows-8-to-per-application-input-language-mode/)