# Windows 10 Dutch with English apps

Tags: windows-10, language, file-association, windows-store-app, english

I've been running into translation errors from Dutch to English, so I've been trying to set apps like Windows store, Spotify, Registry editor and that group policy thing and the program that drove me crazy: Dolby ATMOS for the headset...

I keep finding this post (and post referring to it) and managed to set the setting that allows you to change app language:

[Set Windows 8 to per-application input language mode](https://superuser.com/questions/466180/set-windows-8-to-per-application-input-language-mode/1252223?noredirect=1#comment1839318_1252223)

But I have no idea how I can change the language of apps.  I run Windows 10 Version 1703 Creator Update (KB4038788).

Comment: It's "Creators Update" not "gebaseerde systemen" but that information could just been reduced to 1703.

Comment: Registry Editor, Dolby ATMOS, and Spotify are all desktop applications, the ability to change the language of an application is restricted to UWP applications on Windows 10, but only if those applications have support for that language.  Desktop applications having translation in other languages is 100% up to the developer to provide.

Comment: Ah, that's a good thing to know. I thought that everything downloaded from the store was an app or kinda like an app. I know that the programs i listed have both Dutch and English. I'm using an English account and a Dutch one on my windows 10 and just switch when needed (-_-).